# How to stop counting scores if you already win or lose?

Tags: javascript

It gets score if i click on the red one. If i click on the red ball, even after winning score or losing score it still count. so how to stop counting after specific number?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/riZUx.jpg)

Comment: Please go through [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this may be your solution:

```
function clickHandler(e) {
  var elem= getElementAt(e.getX(), e.getY());
  if(score !=0) 
  {
    if(elem != null && elem.getColor() == Color.red) 
    {
      score++;
    } else {
      score--;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank u so much, that was it! 
15 in winning point and how to make it so after 15 point, make it so counting stops?

Comment: No problem. within the if(score!=0), add && !(score==WIN_SCORE) in this way, reached score=win_score, the if will break

Comment: OMG Thank u so much!  my brain froze and i really couldn't think of a way lol

Comment: You're welcome ahahah ,happens !

Answer (score 0):

set a boolean and prior changing use it in the if statement.

```
if (isPlaying && ...otherConditions) {
   your code to change score here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
< script >


  $(function() {

    // #max number to win is 10

    var score = 0; // set score here

    var Win_Score = 10; //max score to win.

    //on click event to count score
    $("#btn").on('click', function() {

      if (score != null && score <= Win_Score - 1 && score > 0) {


        // if score is null and less then max socre 10 it will increase score by 1 every click until Win_score 10;
        score++;

        console.log(score)

      }

      if (score == 0) {

        // if score 0 it will show you loss and stop counting
        console.log('Loss')


      }

      if (score == 10) {

        // if score 10 it will show you Win and stop counting
        console.log('Win')


      }



    })



  })



  <
  /script>
```

Comment: I set the code according to your code please check and trace it!